# What's the idiomatic way to work with dates without time in golang?

Tags: date, go

I'm writing a REST API in Go, working with dates that don't represent a single point in time.

It's JSON data going to and from the server in "2006-01-02" format, with that data talking to a mysql database using DATE columns.

One thing I've tried is to create a struct that embeds a Time, and implements JSON and SQL conversion interface implementations to be able to correctly interact with the endpoints while still having Time methods available for date math and formatting.  e.g.:

```
package localdate

import (
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "database/sql/driver"
)

type LocalDate struct {
    time.Time
}

func NewLocalDate(year int, month time.Month, day int) LocalDate {
    time := time.Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    return LocalDate{Time: time}
}

const LocalDateFormat = "2006-01-02" // yyyy-mm-dd

func (ld *LocalDate) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // parse and set the ld.Time variable
}

func (ld *LocalDate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(ld.Format(LocalDateFormat))
}

// sql.Scanner implementation to convert a time.Time column to a LocalDate
func (ld *LocalDate) Scan(value interface{}) error {}

// sql/driver.Valuer implementation to go from LocalDate -> time.Time
func (ld *LocalDate) Value() (driver.Value, error)  {}

// used to convert a LocalDate into something we can plug into a query
// we could just use ld.Time, but that would send '2015-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'
// instead of '2015-01-01' for the DATE query parameter.  (Which works for mysql, but is officially invalid SQL)
func (ld *LocalDate) SqlDate() string  {
    return ld.Format(LocalDateFormat)
}
```

And then other structs can be of this type, and get 90% there to representing the date type in my problem domain.

The above code works, but I feel like I'm fighting against the Go current.  So a couple questions for the veterans of the language:

Do you think this code will cause more pain than it'll save?
If so, what style would you recommend?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "dates that don't represent a single point in time"? Are they ranges?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I used the plural form to mean dates in general...for this scenario I'm dealing with one date at a time.

Comment: You could also define your methods on 
    `type LocalDate time.Time`
if you don't need embedding

Comment: Check out this recent Go talk: http://talks.golang.org/2015/json.slide

Answer (score 13):

I use `civil.Date` from the package [cloud.google.com/go/civil](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/civil)

Comment: If you're still new to go as I am - the command to import this module is `go get cloud.google.com/go/civil`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can store your data as `time.Time` but convert it to a string for JSON purposes:

```
type LocalDate struct {
  t time.Time `json:",string"` // might even work anonymously here
}
```

To see how to make this work with SQL: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support

Answer (score 1):

If the project uses Gorm then we can freely use `datatypes.Date` from `gorm.io/datatypes`

```
import "gorm.io/datatypes"

type UserWithDate struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Date datatypes.Date
}

user := UserWithDate{Name: "jinzhu", Date: datatypes.Date(time.Now())}
DB.Create(&user)
// INSERT INTO `user_with_dates` (`name`,`date`) VALUES ("jinzhu","2020-07-17 00:00:00")

DB.First(&result, "name = ? AND date = ?", "jinzhu", datatypes.Date(curTime))
// SELECT * FROM user_with_dates WHERE name = "jinzhu" AND date = "2020-07-17 00:00:00" ORDER BY `user_with_dates`.`id` LIMIT 1
```

Source: [github.com/go-gorm/datatypes#date](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes#date)

Under the hood, it's still `time.Time`, but with zeroed values of the time part.
Example of my usage:

```
// make the time part of datetime equal to zero
date, err := datatypes.Date(time.Now()).Value()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

dateValue := date.(time.Time)
```